# What causes the HTML to look differently based on the way the PHP is placed?

Tags: php, html

Here are the photo examples to illustrate what I mean.

Edit:

```
echo '
    <input type="text" name="city" class="" placeholder="City" disabled="true"/>
                    '.displayStateSelect('state', null).'
    <input type="text" name="zip" class="" placeholder="Zip" disabled="true" />';
```

OR

```
echo '<input type="text" name="city" class="" placeholder="City" disabled="true" />';

displayStateSelect('state', null);

echo '<input type="text" name="zip" class="" placeholder="Zip" disabled="true" />
        </div>
```

**When calling a function during an echo statement:**
[image: Code - inline]
[image: Photo - inline]

**Breaking it apart:**

[image: Code - Broken Apart]
[image: Photo - Broken Apart]

-- Aren't these essentially the same? What causes the display order to change? Does it execute the functions response first then echo the rest (as appears?).

Side question, is that bad practice to call inline echo functions? =\

Comment: Please add the code to the question, don't just crop screenshots, especially not when you don't even show the full lines of code... Also, what does `displayStateSelect` do? I'll assume it returns a value, in which case no, they are in no way the same. The first concats the return to the string being defined, the second does... well nothing :P. If it was `echo displayStateSelect(...)`, that would be another matter.

Comment: The code not pictured is completely irrelevant to the question. It shows exactly what I am asking -- Where the function call is made and why it makes a difference. It also shows the screenshots of the resulting code. I don't see the relevance. Its clear that both photos are of the same code just arranged differently.

Comment: @Imperialized I disagree, please post your code as text.

Comment: It's not irrelevant. For all we know at the end of the line before `displayStateSelect` there is a `'.` not the end of a statement making the code completely different.

Comment: Where is code? Add whatever you can, but dont just add snaps!

Comment: Added the text code to help clarify. Didn't think it would matter in this situation with the screenshots.

Comment: in the first example the php is a quoted string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `displayStateSelect('state', null)` actually writes the `<select>` element to the output buffer via an `echo` or other method instead of using a `return` which would allow you to use your first method.

ie

```
function displayStateSelect($state,$something){
    echo '<select><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>';
}
```

vs

```
function displayStateSelect($state,$something){
    return '<select><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, you should really post your code and not screenshots of the code. The screenshots make it much harder to get the full context of your issue and lead to more speculation about an answer. That being said...

It is displaying like that because you are inserting a function that "echo"s or "print"s it's output inside an echo statement. You need to either not inline the function call to `displayStateSelect()`, so it will produce it's content at the time you desire, or you need to have it `return` it's output instead of outputting it.

Comment: This is all anyone had to say. I get it. I thought that from the get. People just need to learn be respectful. Just ask. Don't always have to be so rude.